# Timer Callback not getting called

Tags: ros, roscpp

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Here Is My timer callback code

```cpp
#include 
#include 
class Timer {
public:
    ros::NodeHandle nh_;
    Timer(ros::NodeHandle* nh) ;
    void init_timers();
    void stateTimerCallback(const ros::TimerEvent& event);

};

Timer::Timer(ros::NodeHandle* nh) : nh_(*nh) {
   Timer::init_timers();
}

void Timer::init_timers()
{
    const bool oneshot = false;
    bool autostart = true;
    ros::Timer timer_ = nh_.createTimer(ros::Duration(1.0),&Timer::stateTimerCallback,this,oneshot,autostart);
    timer_.start() ;
    ROS_INFO("Init_Timer \n");
    printf("Init_Timer\n");
    ROS_DEBUG("Init_Timer\n");

}

void Timer::stateTimerCallback(const ros::TimerEvent& event)
{
    ROS_INFO("I am here\n");
    printf("I am here\n");
    ROS_DEBUG("I am here\n");
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    ros::init(argc,argv,"timer_node");
    ros::NodeHandle nh;
    Timer timer(&nh);
    ros::spin();
    return 0;
}
```

The output i get after running the node

```
$ rosrun timertest timertest_node
[ INFO] [1685511182.674019058]: /timer_node: Init_Timer 

Init_Timer
```

I wait for 1 minute but still there was no output from callback. What might be the reason ?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/416000/timer-callback-not-getting-called/) by [GauNav](https://answers.ros.org/users/151868/gaunav/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2023-05-31

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [GauNav](https://answers.ros.org/users/151868/gaunav/) on 2023-05-31**:
Really sorry if my question comes out as silly. I am not completely sure about working of roscpp.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi!

From the [roscpp tutorials](http://wiki.ros.org/roscpp/Overview/Timers):

> Note that, in this example, the timer
> object must be a member of the class
> for callbacks to fire.

Thus, you should have

```
class Timer {
public:
    ros::NodeHandle nh_;
    Timer(ros::NodeHandle* nh) ;
    void init_timers();
    void stateTimerCallback(const ros::TimerEvent& event);
    ros::Timer timer_;
};
```

and modify the line where you call `nh_.createTimer()` as follows:

```
timer_ = nh_.createTimer(ros::Duration(1.0),&Timer::stateTimerCallback,this,oneshot,autostart);
```

Hope this helps!

---

Originally posted by [bluegiraffe-sc](https://answers.ros.org/users/69377/bluegiraffe-sc/) with karma: 221 on 2023-05-31

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2023-05-31**:
Summarising: the `timer_` object only "exists" as long as `init_timers()` is executing. Which is perhaps a couple hundred nanoseconds. It then immediately gets destroyed. No `timer_` -> no callbacks.

**Comment by [GauNav](https://answers.ros.org/users/151868/gaunav/) on 2023-06-01**:
Thanks @bluegiraffe-sc , @gvdhoorn .